# How can I create view with multiple name of columns?

Tags: sql

I have problem with question in SQL, I need to join all tables from base but when I write this question I get only values from table "klienci" in order of rest tables. I need to use alias also, because next I need to create view with this question:

```
SELECT idk, klienci.nazwa AS nazwa_klienta, miasto, adres, telefon
FROM klienci
  LEFT JOIN zamow ON idk=k_id
  LEFT JOIN detal_zamow ON idz=z_id
  LEFT JOIN produkty ON idp=p_id;
```

Comment: Please prepend each column name with the table alias of it. We cannot guess to which table each column belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT k.idk, k.nazwa AS nazwa_klienta, k.miasto, k.adres, k.telefon,
z.*,det_zam.*,prod.*
FROM klienci as k
LEFT JOIN zamow as z ON k.idk=z.k_id
LEFT JOIN detal_zamow as det_zam ON k.idz=det_zam.z_id  --????
LEFT JOIN produkty as prod ON k.idp=prod.p_id; --???
```

Not sure, but may be something like this. Without tables structure not sure about the two last JOINs

Comment: It shows now that 'Unknown column 'k.idz' in 'on clouse'

Comment: @Strzelu65 What columns do you want from the other tables?

Comment: Okey I edited it a little bit and now it works. Correct is

CREATE VIEW wszyscy_klienci AS SELECT k.idk, k.nazwa AS nazwa_klienta, k.miasto, k.adres, k.telefon, z.*,det_zam.*,produkty.* FROM klienci as k LEFT JOIN zamow as z ON k.idk=z.k_id LEFT JOIN detal_
zamow as det_zam ON idz=det_zam.z_id LEFT JOIN produkty ON idp=p_id;